# How to put these buttons next to eachother?

Tags: html, css

Hey i would like to put these 2 buttons next to eachother put 1 keeps going under the other. How can i fix this?
**CSS:**

```css
a.button1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.35em 1.2em;
  border: 0.1em solid white;
  /* margin:0 0.3em 0.3em 0; */
  border-radius: 0.12em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin-left: 1360px;
  width: 5%
}

a.button1:hover {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

@media all and (max-width:30em) {
  a.button1 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0.4em auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-headertje">
  <span class="close" style="color:white;" id="kruisje">&times;</span>
  <center>
    <h2 style="color:black;">Specificaties</h2>
  </center>
  <a style="cursor:pointer; text-align:center;" class="button1" style="width:5%; ">Button</a>
  <a style="cursor:pointer; text-align:center;" class="button1" style="width:5%; ">Button</a>
</div>
```

[image: This happens]

Comment: Remove the `display:block`.

Comment: Use `display:inline-block`. (If you just remove it, it will fall back to the default `inline`, and then specifying a width won’t work any more.)

Comment: Or you can use flex to implement this

Comment: under media? I already tried that but didnt affect it. @misorude

Comment: Ah no, of course it can’t work with inline-block either, as long as both buttons have `margin-left: 1360px;` …

Answer (score 0):

Use inline in the css you use. block doesn't help you

```
.inline {
   display:inline-block;
   margin-right:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change below HTML, CSS and you're done...

```
<div class="button-par">
    <a style="cursor:pointer; text-align:center;" class="button1" style="width:5%; ">Button</a>
    <a style="cursor:pointer; text-align:center;" class="button1" style="width:5%; ">Button</a>
</div>

a.button1 {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px;
    color: #000;
    width: max-content;
}
```

<

```css
.button-par {
  float:right;
  width: max-content;
}
a.button1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.35em 1.2em;
  border-radius: 0.12em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: 5%
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #000;
  width: max-content;
}

a.button1:hover {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

@media all and (max-width:30em) {
  a.button1 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0.4em auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-headertje">
  <span class="close" style="color:white;" id="kruisje">&times;</span>
  <center>
    <h2 style="color:black;">Specificaties</h2>
  </center>
  <div class="button-par">
  <a style="cursor:pointer; text-align:center;" class="button1" style="width:5%; ">Button</a>
  <a style="cursor:pointer; text-align:center;" class="button1" style="width:5%; ">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your `margin-left: 1360px` that's causing the problem, as it's applied to both buttons and pushing them both by that much.

You can just do `float:right` to get them aligned to the right, or better yet, wrap them in a div and float that to the right.

```
a.button1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.35em 1.2em;
  border: 0.1em solid white;
  /* margin:0 0.3em 0.3em 0; */
  border-radius: 0.12em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float:right;
  width: 5%
}
```

Or with a div:

```
<div class="modal-headertje">
  <span class="close" style="color:white;" id="kruisje">&times;</span>
  <center>
    <h2 style="color:black;">Specificaties</h2>
  </center>
  <div class="float-right">
      <a style="cursor:pointer; text-align:center;" class="button1" style="width:5%; ">Button</a>
      <a style="cursor:pointer; text-align:center;" class="button1" style="width:5%; ">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>

.float-right {
  float:right;
}
a.button1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.35em 1.2em;
  border: 0.1em solid white;
  /* margin:0 0.3em 0.3em 0; */
  border-radius: 0.12em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 5%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not good to hardcode `margin-left` to align the button in the right because every device can have different width so it can cause horizontal scroll problem for other devices.

It's always good to use `text-align` with the inline elements instead of using float.

You need to do the following to solve your problem:

```
    <div class="modal-headertje">
        <span class="close" style="color:white;" id="kruisje">&times;</span>
        <center>
            <h2 style="color:black;">Specificaties</h2>
        </center>
        <div style="text-align: right">
            <a style="cursor:pointer; text-align:center;" class="button1" style="width:5%; ">Button</a>
            <a style="cursor:pointer; text-align:center;" class="button1" style="width:5%; ">Button</a>
        </div>
    </div>

a.button1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.35em 1.2em;
  border: 0.1em solid white;
  /* margin:0 0.3em 0.3em 0; */
  border-radius: 0.12em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: 5%
}
```